# About WhatsApp voice record

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, media-files

Someone sent me a voice record in my WhatsApp, and the problem is I can play it only in my WhatsApp. When I log out from WhatsApp and try to play it from my phone memory it's not playing. And I try to copy it into my external memory but it's not copied. If there is any solution for this, tell me please.

Comment: Those files format are only read by WhatsApp I guess

Comment: @esQmo_ it would strike me odd, if only WhatsApp was able to play OPUS audio.

Answer (score 0):

The audio recorded in WhatsApp will be in the format of .opus. It cannot be played by apps. Just change the format to .mp3 by renaming the file in explorer. Now it can be played.